# Images not in center in bootstrap xs column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML code:

```
 <div class="row">
               <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
                   <div id="what-we-do">
                       <a href="builtupletters.htm"><img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="images/builtupletters370x280.png"></a>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
                   <div id="what-we-do">
                       <a href="builtupletters.htm"><img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="images/builtupletters370x280.png"></a>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
                   <div id="what-we-do">
                       <a href="builtupletters.htm"><img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="images/builtupletters370x280.png"></a>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
                   <div id="what-we-do">
                       <a href="builtupletters.htm"><img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="images/builtupletters370x280.png"></a>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
                   <div id="what-we-do">
                       <a href="builtupletters.htm"><img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="images/builtupletters370x280.png"></a>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
                   <div id="what-we-do">
                       <a href="builtupletters.htm"><img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="images/builtupletters370x280.png"></a>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
```

Using bootstraps column method, in lg and md this displays as 6 images, in two rows, 3 images in each row. The images respond and resize and it look how I want it. At sm, the columns then expand so that every image is stacked ontop of one another. I have used the following CSS so that the image centers iself.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
#what-we-do {
    margin-left: 190px;
    margin-right: 190px;
}
```

}

However, in xs the images are stacked one ontop of the other like md, but I cannot center them. I have tried to use the CSS that I used in md to achieve the same outcome however it does not work because xs can be a many number of widths, auto and inherit dont work either. Can anyone help me to center these images within the xs column class.

Comment: what css you written for "img-responsive img-rounded"

Comment: Well for starters, 'style="text-center' sure won't be doing the trick.

Comment: @ganeshsatpute I have no CSS for either of these

Comment: @SeanStopnik well I've tried that but no luck.

Comment: updated ans please try

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to apply width :100% and height : auto and text-align:center  for parent class of img

Comment: Do I do this and this only? Because that didn't do anything?

Comment: can you create jsfiddle for better understanding

Comment: I cant really because I have images that are the right size, and it wont ever run properly